# Can we determine a proper verb form of "exegesis" for Biblical scholars to use?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, verbs, greek, derivational-morphology

This is related to [a conversation here in EL&U SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106062/religious-use-of-exegete/106066?noredirect=1#comment216924_106066).
Apparently the noun *exegete* is being used as verb in religious circles.

For Biblical Scholars, the word *exegesis* carries with it a connotation of properly drawing out of Scripture only what is there rather than reading into it what is not there. No other English word immediately brings to mind that specific meaning.

Webster's New World Dictionary, 4th ed., indicates that the probable origin of the word *exegesis* is the Greek noun *exegesis*, "explanation", which in turn appears to come from the Greek verb *exegeisthai*, "to lead, explain".

If the misuse of the word *exegete* arises from the lack of a verb form of this word, then could we not use this Greek source to introduce a proper verb, i.e. *exegisthai*. That is difficult to pronounce; but, if there are other English words derived from Greek words with the same verb ending, one could see how that verb ending comes over into English and provide the same verb ending for our word. Then we would have a proper verb to introduce which carries the desired meaning and is easily recognizable as related to exegesis.

Does anyone have any idea as to how this Greek ending comes over into English?

[I found this page pertaining to Greek words coming into English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_of_Greek_origin#The_written_form_of_Greek_words_in_English)
According to what it says here very few verbs come over from Greek, such as *baptize* and *ostracize*.  So, what about *exegize*?

Comment: The reason why the word "exegete" is used instead of explain or interpret is to set this kind of explanation or interpretation apart from other uses. Exegete is typically reserved for use with sacred texts of various faiths. Dmjolnir 23:33, 2 July 2011 (UTC) http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:exegete

Comment: Related: Religious use of “exegete”  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106062/14666

Comment: The form ?"*exegize*" has indeed been used earlier. I do not think ELU can rule on its validity, though. The right thing probably would be to write to OxfordDictionaries (there's a great affinity for new and needy words & expressions there) with some background research in support. See also below.

Comment: "... new and not a static text to exegize; " (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ckiwzTt-rRAC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=exegize+-exegesis&source=bl&ots=Nt4iBGsoYP&sig=E0S4kgAPShTNAE9WyfLhX6fjZc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t5A5UfWhHMztrQf6j4DACw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=exegize%20-exegesis&f=false)

Comment: Some Muslim commentators exegize the word "Messiah" to mean "wanderer." Jesus had no place to lay his head. (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=BjC7K1j_AT8C&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=exegize+-exegesis&source=bl&ots=I72OZF-h-p&sig=5cYSqam-Mx0AQs3r0EdbGbM-Qek&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t5A5UfWhHMztrQf6j4DACw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=exegize%20-exegesis&f=false)

Comment: @Kris, What is ELU?

Comment: This Q&A site is ELU (English Language & Usage).

Comment: There's always the option of not forcing a single word and getting the more than adequate "make/write/produce/etc an exegesis".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, your only option seems to be **exegese** (or possibly *exegeze*, but probably not), if you must have a verb that would be acceptable to the OED.

But it should be noted that, for what is probably the majority of words on *-sis*, no verb is ever used; perhaps recasting your sentence would be a better idea, e.g. *she interpreted the passage*. Using the Greek infinitive *exegeisthai* is a bad idea that will send classicists off screaming.

The only traditional way of forming a verb based on a Greek word on -*sis* that I am aware of is *-se*:

> Parenthesis => parenthese
>
> Diagnosis => diagnose
>
> Paralysis => paralyse
>
> Basis/-se => base
>
> Metamorphosis => metamorphose

Occasionally, modern forms on *-sise* are created, as in those based on *-thesis* (*hypothesise, synthesise*); I can't think of any other example. Those few Greek words on *-sis* whose noun-equivalents already end on *-se* in English also use *-se* for the verb, as in *phrase* and *base*.

For forms on *-ise* and *-yse*, you may encounter *-ize* and *-yze* in America, respectively, and possibly sometimes elsewhere too, so *exegeze* may be considered a valid alternative depending on your local tradition. However, this strictly has nothing to do with the formation of an English word based on Greek, but rather on regional variations within English. Lastly, I do not believe Americans normally do this with words on *-ese/-eze* (they stick with *-ese*: only after *-i-* and *-y-* is this *z* commonly used), but that's your call.

Your examples *ostracize* and *baptize* are different, because they have somehow retained or regained the *z* that was originally there in Greek (*ostrakizein, baptizein*), as opposed to in *exegeisthai* and most other verbs. The same applies to *apologize/apologizein.* This confusion is the reason (most?) British publishers and style books use *-ise/-yse* for verbs based on Greek nouns on *-sis* (Oxford and Cambridge alike, I think), like *analyse*; but they do often do use *-ize* for other Greek verbs, like *baptize*, and for words taken from non-Greek stems, like *immunize, realize, colonize* (either Oxford or Cambridge—I forgot). They usually do not, however, use *-yze* where Greek had no *-uzein* (so practically never). I know, it is a bit tiresome having to remember the exact origin of such words—I am usually too lazy to do so, I must confess.

The *-i-* in **exegise/exegize* is not really defensible, because that is normally not done with words derived from *-esis*, but only with those derived from *-isis*. The *-ize* in *energize* comes from Greek *-(e)izein*, as *energy* comes from *energ(e)ia*; the *-i-* in *apologize* from Greek *-izein* as in *apology*, from *apologia*. The *-y* in English represents *-(e)ia* in most Greek (and Latin) words, and hence nouns on *-y* in English have verbs on *-ise/ize*.

Comment: And in your opinion, would it be possible to introduce such a verb even after the noun is already being used as a verb?

Comment: Is your last paragraph a general statement (for example applying to the word *baptize*) or specific to inventing *exegise*?

Comment: @Sarah: You mean if people use *exegesis* as a verb? That looks rather dubious to me, possibly uneducated...I would dismiss it out of hand, to be honest.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Added another paragraph on *-ize*: I believe it does not apply to words like *baptize*, which already had the *z* in Greek.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I mean they are currently using exegete as a verb and would it be batting against the wind to use exegise / exegize / exegese  since they would be more sound linguistically and still recognizable as verb forms of exegesis.

Comment: @Sarah I rather like *exegise* and as Kris has shown it is in use. Cerberus caught the import of my comment.

Comment: @AndrewLeach,  Kris showed that exegize is in use.  Are you saying exegise is better?  And is there a way to find out how much either of these is in use already and in what context?

Comment: @Sarah: Oh, oops, I see I made the same typo twice: the correct *-z-* form would be *exegeze*, not *exegize*. I don't think the forms with *-i-* are defensible. Yes, I would by all means use *exegese* over *exegete*: it is less ugly, more correct, and easier to recognise to boot! I see I made another mistake btw.: I don't believe American spelling ever uses *-eze* for *-ese* (just *-ize/-yze* only).

Comment: @AndrewLeach  So exegese (pronounced as "s" or "z"?) would be the most recognizable and most correct verb form.  You are saying, it would be preferable over exegeze/exegize since there was originally no z in the word?

Comment: @Sarah Yes. In fact *exegese* can be found: [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exegise%2Cexegize%2Cexegese%2Cexegete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) but a corpus search through COCA would be more reliable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It almost looks like exegese shows up in maybe German literature? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Sarah I guess it's a German word. I'm not schooled enough in German to say (it wasn't part of the O-level syllabus thirty years ago!) This is one reason why Ngrams need to be treated with care and a corpus search is better.

Comment: @Sarah: I would probably pronounce *exegese* "z", like most other Greek-derived verbs on *-se* (*base* being the exception?). The *i* would be undesirable because there is no *-isis* in the noun, and there was no *-i-* or *-ei-* in the Greek, unlike the *i* in *crisis* etc. The *z* is undesirable because there was no z in the Greek verb, and Americans normally only use *-ze* after *i* or *y*, not after *e*.

Comment: @Cerberus very good.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I found [exegese in French](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/ex%c3%a9g%c3%a8se).  It looks right but it is still a noun in French.

Comment: @Sarah: Right, *-se* is the regular French form for Greek *-sis*. So *exegese* is a noun in most other languages than English, because they followed the French tradition. I'm afraid no English verb was ever in common use. Nor was any such verb in another language except in Greek itself, I expect.

Comment: @Sarah: Yup! It comes from the same Greek verb, *hêgeisthai*, "to lead; to opine", related to *hegemony*. The prefixes are used to alter the basic meaning.

Comment: Sorry Cerberus, I deleted a couple questions because I did not want to bombard you folks.  But I believe you just answered that the verb form for eisegesis would be eisegese.  Thank you.

Comment: @Cerberus, What is OED?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7822/discussion-between-sarah-and-cerberus)

Answer (score 0):

The word *exegete*, apparently from *exegetic*, is an example of back-formation. English users intuitively drop the suffix to return it to its root form, even though, as in this case, that root form never really existed. But it is a completely valid way to create new words.

There is a list of other back-formed words here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_back-formations

Answer (score -2):

I have a Biblical world-view, and using exegete as a verb seems to exactly fit within that world-view; when asking someone to exegete from their world-view, whatever it may be.

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm curious on how to support this. Can you elaborate how that fits in a _Biblical_ word-view? Do you have on-line examples that support this? Maybe contrast with another word that might be for another world view. Also, by 'Biblical' do you mean Christian or Protestant or Abrahamic or what?

Comment: Please provide substatiation for your answer rather than just pointing out your opinion.

Comment: I only became aware of the word (exegete) in the context of Biblical teaching. So for me it has a far more profound meaning than; explain, expound, extrapolate, etc. To truly understand the basis for one's position on a topic, I would ask them to exegete from their world-view or perhaps, from the thesis of their world-view. By Biblical I mean; everything that I am aware of, is understood by means of the Bible. The word exegete already exists and the form of it seems to be verb-like. So I will continue to use it as a verb.